# What is the best way to pass git config to argocd

Tags: git, kubernetes, argoproj, argocd

I am running a argocd command

`argocd repo add https://gitlab.<mysite>.com/<repo>.git`

I get error and is known one.
Now, to avoid this, I have o set ~/.gitconfig in argocd kubernetes pod as follows

```
[http "https://gitlab.<mysite>.com"]
proxy = http://www-proxy.<proxy-server>:8080
```

How can I pass this config to argocd command?

P.S. I have tried to write the above two lines in ~/.gitconfig of argocd server pod

Also, I have tried following command

`argocd repo add https://gitlab.<mysite>/<repo>.git --config '[http "https://gitlab.<mysite>.com"] \n proxy = http://www-proxy.<proxy-server>:8080'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you add a single repo, you can specify the proxy for this repo when you add it. You would need to use:

`argocd repo add https://gitlab.<mysite>/<repo>.git --proxy http://www-proxy.<proxy-server>:8080`